# Subclass from sympy.Function with predefined variable

Tags: python, inheritance, sympy

I'm trying to make a new class called `MyFunction` which is an *One Variable Function*.

It inherits from `sympy.Function` to get the same properties, but I'm having problems with the `__new__` method.

My goal is to make it work

```py
import sympy as sp
# class definition
x = MyFunction("x")
dx = x.dt
```

The equivalent code, which already works:

```py
import sympy as sp
t = sp.symbols("t")
x = sp.Function("x")(t)
dx = sp.diff(x, t)
```

The class that inherits from `sp.Function`

```py
import sympy as sp

class MyFunction(sp.Function):

    def __new__(cls, name):
        t = sp.symbols("t")
        # Now we do just like 'sp.Function("x")(t)'
        self = super().__new__(cls, name)(t)  # Error
        self.time = t
        return self

    @property
    def dt(self):
        return sp.diff(self, self.time)


x = MyFunction("x")
dx = x.dt
print(x)  # expected print 'x(t)'
print(dx)  # expected print 'Derivative(x(t), t)'
```

The received error is

```
self = super().__new__(cls, name)(t)  # Error
TypeError: 'MyFunction' object is not callable
```

I tried to inherit from an another class (like `sp.core.function.UndefinedFunction`), but it gives the error

```
AttributeError: 'x' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Now I have no idea how to proceed and solve it.

Comment: What's wrong with the code that already works?

Comment: The code doesn't  have some functions that I want to add. For exemple, in my ideal code I hide the parameter ```t``` from the user, and I allow only to get the second derivative (that is, apply ```sp.diff``` twice) in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
import sympy as sp

class MyFunction(sp.Function):

    def __new__(cls, name):
        t = sp.symbols("t")
        self = sp.Function(name)(t)
        self.time = t
        self.dt = sp.diff(self, self.time)
        return self

x = MyFunction("x")
dx = x.dt

print(x)
print(dx)
```

Result:

```
x(t)
Derivative(x(t), t)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually create an instance of the MyFunction class. You can just replace the class with a function that does the same.